# Transform timeseries dataframe with start/stop times labelled

Tags: python, pandas

Say I generate a dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[False]*2 + ['info']]*20 ,columns=['trip_start','trip_end','info'],index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01',freq='d', periods=20))
df.iat[1,0] = df.iat[3,1] = True
df.iat[10,0] = df.iat[15,1] = True
```

So my dataframe looks like this:

```
index       trip_start  trip_end  info
2019-01-01       False     False  info
2019-01-02        True     False  info
2019-01-03       False     False  info
2019-01-04       False      True  info
2019-01-05       False     False  info
2019-01-06       False     False  info
2019-01-07       False     False  info
2019-01-08       False     False  info
2019-01-09       False     False  info
2019-01-10       False     False  info
2019-01-11        True     False  info
2019-01-12       False     False  info
2019-01-13       False     False  info
2019-01-14       False     False  info
2019-01-15       False     False  info
2019-01-16       False      True  info
2019-01-17       False     False  info
2019-01-18       False     False  info
2019-01-19       False     False  info
2019-01-20       False     False  info
```

I need to transform this dataframe such that each row is a trip:

```
index start_date    end_date    start_info end_info
    1 2019-01-02    2019-01-04  info       info
    2 2019-01-11    2019-01-16  info       info
```

I can do this by iterating though row by row, but I'm hoping there's a clever way to do this. The trip start/end times are guaranteed to be in order in the original dataframe (ie alternating trip start/trip end).

Comment: Do `start` end `end` always occur alternatively? Would they happen at the same day?

Comment: Can trips overlap?  How are they handled if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you can simply make a dataframe of the starts and a dataframe of the ends then concatenate the two, assuming that the alternating order is guaranteed.

The following should do the trick:

```
df1 = df[df['trip_start']]
df1['start_date'] = df1.index
df1 = df1.drop(columns=['trip_start', 'trip_end'])

df2 = df[df['trip_end']]
df2['end_date'] = df2.index
df2 = df2.drop(columns=['trip_start', 'trip_end'])

new_df = pd.concat(df1, df2, axis=1)
new_df = new_df.reset_index()  # get rid of dates in the index
```

Answer (score 0):

If trips don't overlap and span at least two days, we can do:

```
new_df = (df.assign(cols=df.trip_start + df.trip_end * 2,
                    idx=df.trip_start.cumsum())
            .query('cols>0')
            .pivot(index='idx', columns='cols', values=['index','info'])
         )
```

output:

```
           index              info      
cols           1           2     1     2
idx                                     
1     2019-01-02  2019-01-04  info  info
2     2019-01-11  2019-01-16  info  info
```

And you can rename accordingly.